# Magento: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I'm getting this after a migration.

In the site: `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'nieve_magento.mage_log_visitor_info' doesn't exist`.

In the admin site: `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'nieve_magento.mage_sales_flat_order' doesn't exist`.

I have seen that maybe I need to recreate the tables, but I didn't find the values for those tables. It is something more, I see that my db ends after the table `log_visitor`...

Comment: My guess would be that your script timedout when you tried to export the database from your original host (you mention migration).  Go back to the original server and re-export the database.